# Loop over time-series object in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have a time-series object as:

```
 seq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-09-01"),as.POSIXct("2015-09-02"), by = "120 mins")
 ob <- xts(rnorm(length(seq)),seq) # xts object
```

One important property of `ob` is that it gets updated in real-time, i.e., new observation get appended to it by using `rbind`. Therefore, I don't know the exact length of this object. Now, I want to read the `ob` row by row and perform my required operation. Let us assume that I will read the row of `ob` and then add this row to another static time-series (`xts`) object.  How should I read the `ob` row by row? Till now, I approached it as

```
  i <- 1
  l <- ob[i,]
  while(NROW(l)) # Check I have a row to read
  {   
      print(l) # dummy operation
      i <- i+1
      l <- ob[i,] 
  }
```

This code does its job, but it results in error as

```
Error in `[.xts`(ob, i, ) : subscript out of bounds
```

I understand the error. I want to know, is there a better way to read `xts` objects row by row?

Comment: I'd try to vectorize that operation to avoid the loop. But to answer your question, I think you want to use the `length` of `ob[, 1]` or rather `nrow(ob)` in each iteration -- as the `length` of what you are currently checking will be always one (column), so not respecting the last row and trying to read infinitive number of records.

Comment: I got your point and I have changed `length` to `NROW`, but still it is not solving the issue fully.

Comment: Maybe just encapsulate your last assignment in a try()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this do what you want?

```
library(xts)

seq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-09-01"),as.POSIXct("2015-09-02"), by = "120 mins")
ob <- xts(rnorm(length(seq)),seq) # xts object

i <- 1
l <- ob[i,]
while(NROW(l))
{
    print(l)
    i <- i+1
    l <- try(ob[i,], silent=TRUE)
    if(class(l)[1]=="try-error") break
}
```